# ECMA Class - Return HTML and fire (class) function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

may it isn´t possible, but i´m full of hope.

I´m trying to learn ECMA 6, and just got to the "Classes". Now my class return some HMTML `getHTML()` with an button in it. now i´m trying to bind an event and fire another function.

```
getHTML() {
    return `
        <button id="${ this.getId(false) }" class="btn btn-default" 
        onclick="${ this.setActive()}">${ this.getName() }</button>
    `
}
```

My second function, which i want ot fire, looks like this:

```
setActive() { 
    this.getActive() ? this.isActive = false : this.isActive = true;
    alert(this.getActive()); 
}
```

The `oncklick = ...` was my try, but it doenst work (who would have thought that?).

Is there a chance to get this to work?

Comment: not much code in your post, but my guess is `bind` issues. try to `bind`  your  methods inside the constructor `this.getActive = this.getActive.bind(this)`. or use arrow function which will use a lexical context for the `this` key word: `getHTML = () => {...}` `setActive = () => {...}`

Comment: Just don't use HTML strings. Create DOM elements and install event handlers properly!

Comment: worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are effectivly returning a String.

```
`<button onClick="${this.doSomething()}"></button>`
```

Will call `this.doSomething()` directly and the return value `.toString()` will be inserted in the result.

Example:

```
function test () { console.log('###') }

const f = `test=${test()}`

// logs ###

console.log(f) //"test=undefined"
```

I guess you want to add an Event Listener on the Button, but therefore you need turn the String into a DOM node first.

Comment: I just created an element, added the event listener and return my element, now all is working fine, thanks u too.